Spring Security - BFF - not redirecting and Token Relay not able to access Principal
When I try to access a Resource Server endpoint through a Spring Cloud Gateway instance configured with oauth2Login and the TokenRelay filter, it just goes straight to that - without checking if the User Agent holds an authenticated session, instead of re-directing to the Auth Server, if the session is invalid. The later is what I believe should happen. So my question is:
How do I configure Spring Cloud Gateway to redirect to login (on the authorization server) when a request to a downstream service does not have the context of an authorized session?
A user session in Angular definitely exists (ClientSessionID) - I can also see it in the session folder in Redis:

Note:
when I initially try to login from Angular, I call http://localhost:9090/oauth2/authorization/in-house-auth-server? - which redirects me to the Auth Server (9090, is the port of the BFF). That then redirects to http://localhost:7080/auth/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=bff_client&scope=openid&state=cspAnrEz2W4ZjQFBxBZnlB....etc.) (7080 is the port of reverse proxy, and 7080/auth, redirects to the auth server with a port of 6060)
I believe the problem maybe somewhere here, but I'm not sure:
@Configuration
internal class RoutingConfig(
    private val serverProperties: ServerProperties,
) {

    @Bean
    fun routeLocator(builder: RouteLocatorBuilder): RouteLocator {
        return builder.routes()
            // routing for Resource Server
            .route("resource-server") { r ->
                r.path("/api${serverProperties.resourceServerPrefix}/**")
                    .filters { f ->
                        f.filter { exchange, chain ->
                            println("Request Headers: ${exchange.request.headers}")
                            // add custom filter logic here if needed
                            chain.filter(exchange)
                        }
                            .removeRequestHeader("Cookie")
                            .dedupeResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "RETAIN_UNIQUE")
                            .dedupeResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "RETAIN_UNIQUE")
                    }
                    .uri(serverProperties.resourceServerUri)
            }
            .build()
    }
}

Or it's somewhere in my main security chain:

Main Spring Security Chain Configuration

Also the Token Gateway Relay (I have a custom implementation that also checks for whether the access token has expired, and creates a new one, if it has, using the refresh token), tries to get the principal: taken from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H44EeDG39VE, keeps returning:
AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]


as though the BFF cannot see the authenticated session with Angular (or the one that the BFF saved earlier to Redis)? This may also be the root cause to Problem 1, why the BFF is not redirecting to the Auth Server, when an attempt to access a secure Resource Server endpoint is made.

Here is an extract of the code that tries to get the principal:
/**
     * Adds access token to header
     * Also checks if it has expired. If it has, creates a new one (using the refresh token)
     */
    override fun apply(config: NameConfig): GatewayFilter {
        return GatewayFilter { exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: GatewayFilterChain ->
            exchange.getPrincipal<Principal>()
                .filter { principal: Principal? ->
                    if (principal != null) {
                        println("Principal received: $principal")
                    } else {
                        println("No Principal found")
                    }
                    principal is OAuth2AuthenticationToken
                }
                .cast(OAuth2AuthenticationToken::class.java)
                .flatMap { authentication: OAuth2AuthenticationToken ->
                    getAuthorizedClient(
                        exchange,
                        authentication
                    )
                }
                .flatMap { authenticationPair ->
                    if (shouldRefresh(authenticationPair.oAuth2AuthorizedClient)) {
                        refreshAuthorizedClient(
                            exchange,
                            authenticationPair.oAuth2AuthorizedClient,
                            authenticationPair.oAuth2AuthenticationToken
                        )
                    } else {
                        Mono.just(authenticationPair.oAuth2AuthorizedClient)
                    }
                }
                .map { obj: OAuth2AuthorizedClient -> obj.accessToken }
                .map { token: OAuth2AccessToken ->
                    withBearerAuth(
                        exchange,
                        token
                    )
                }
                .defaultIfEmpty(exchange)
                .flatMap { modifiedExchange ->
                    chain.filter(modifiedExchange)
                }
        }
    }

My Routing Classes, Global Filters, and Custom Token Relay filter can be found here:

BFF Gateway Basic Routing
BFF Global Filters
Custom Token Relay Gateway Filter Factory

UPDATE
Even though it was in the oauthlogin configuration, I forgot to set this separately again, in the main security chain.
// security context
http.securityContextRepository(redisSecurityContextRepository)

It now gets the right security context from Redis. So this may have been the cause of the above problem (though I still need to do some more testing...)

this is way to many questions in a single question, you need to be more focused and ask single questions that have single answers. I started reading and gave up after i had read 20% of the question. And dont link to huge full code, include the relevant code parts in your question and make it easy for us to run parts of your code. Produce a MINIMAL reproducible example, imagen yourself if someone said "i have problem here is my full enterprise application of 300 000 lines of code" you need to slim it down.

Thanks. I've trimmed the post down based on your advice

Redirecting unauthorized requests to login
You need 3 things:

a request matcher with anything but permitAll()
something to handle login (formLogin or oauth2Login)
a (Server)AuthenticationEntryPoint setting the response status with something in the 3xx range

@Bean
ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
    // You probably want to read this from application properties
    final var location = "http://localhost:9090/oauth2/authorization/in-house-auth-server";

    return (ServerWebExchange exchange, AuthenticationException ex) -> {
        final var response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND);
        response.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "OAuth realm=%s".formatted(location));
        response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, location);

        final var buffer = response.bufferFactory().wrap("Unauthorized. Please authenticate at %s".formatted(location).getBytes());

        return response.writeWith(Flux.just(buffer));
    }
}

@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain clientFilterChain(
        ServerHttpSecurity http,
        ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {

    http.authorizeExchange(registry -> {
        registry.anyExchange().authenticated();
    });

    http.oauth2Login(oauth2 -> {});

    http.exceptionHandling(exceptions -> {
        exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    });

    return http.build();
}

No need to delete the cookie for a preceding invalid session or whatever.
Why you should not configure a BFF like that
An OAuth2 BFF is a gateway for a REST API, and RESTful APIs should meet the HTTP status specification.
Because 302 means Found and not  Unauthorized, a REST API should answer 401 to requests when an authorization is expected but not provided (a session cookie referencing a valid session in the case where the REST backend is an OAuth2 BFF).
A frontend should handle 401 when consuming a REST API, just like it should handle 403 and other error codes. In an Angular app, handling 401 to trigger login can be easily made with an interceptor (set window.location.href with a URI pointing to the BFF authorization code initiation endpoint).
Configuring the authentication entry point to return a 302 is fine in a Spring application rendering the UI with Thymeleaf, JSP, or whatever, but not in a gateway for a REST API. In addition to the problem with HTTP status above:

Resource access policy should be the responsibility of resource servers. Allowing access to anonymous requests is one of the many possiblities. Other frequently used policies are requiring a client to be granted a given scope, a resource owner to be granted a given authority or have a given relation to the accessed resource (be the author of a blog post, the customer having passed an order, etc.). Taking the decision to redirect to login on the gateway breaks access control responsibility assignment.
In the case where there is more than one possible login option (in the case of oauth2Login, more than one registration with authorization_code), the Spring application needs to prompt the user for which one he wants to use. For that, it needs to render a web page. It's a pain to create and maintain a 3rd UI with the same look and feel (there are already the frontend and the authorization server login forms). Plus, it would be a pretty bad user experience when the frontend is a mobile app.
Unless the BFF and the authorization server are served with the same origin (reverse proxy?), a redirection during a REST call makes the 2nd request cross-origin (the redirection is followed by the frontend internal HTTP client). This can create tricky CORS errors for something that should not be a cross-origin request: in the authorization code flow, the user switches from the main frontend to the authorization server's one. In the OAuth2 spec, there are just redirections, no REST requests between the main and authorization server frontends.

Notes
You are overriding much more Spring code than necessary. As you are obviously not a (Spring) Security expert, this will lead to many problems and security breaches.

I have a custom implementation that also checks for whether the access token has expired, and creates a new one

This is a sample of something you should not be doing. Spring Cloud Gateway TokenRelay filter already does it. It internally uses the ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager which refreshes expired tokens as well as those expiring within the next minute. This protects against most token expirations during network calls.
I believe I already pointed you to this Baeldung article I wrote. It exposes a working solution for the BFF pattern and includes an Angular frontend. Note that in the sample app, the REST request to a protected resource is sent by a component displayed only when the user is authenticated, which makes the 401 interceptor unnecessary. Also, the tutorial does not use Spring Session (not directly related to the subject). A system with a more serious frontend and a scalable BFF would probably use both.

Thanks ch4mp. Yes, I'm not expert, just trying to learn as I go along. What you write makes a lot of sense. So I should (i) use the default TokenRelay, not my custom one (ii) then I need a authentication endpoint (which returns 3xx on authentication failures..?). The problem with the security context was a bug in my Redis implementation in the repository version of authroized client, not creating the correct redis prefix - so that's been fixed. So when I'm authenticated but not authorized Angular should get a 401. Otherwise, if I'm not authenicated, it should get a 3xx? - slowly getting there!

To clarify, you mention "authentication entry point to return a 302 is fine in a Spring application rendering the UI with Thymeleaf, JSP, or whatever, but not in a gateway for a REST API" - I'm using Angular, with reverse proxy, to a BFF, to a Rest API. Can the BFF authentication handler still return a 302. Would that be ok?

I explained how to return a 302 because this is your question, but I think that my answer is clear about the fact that a BFF shouldn't do that: it is a gateway for a REST API (the name of the Spring project for that even is Spring Cloud Gateway) and a REST API should return 401. Just let all requests  routed with the TokenRelay go through the gateway, let the downstream resource server(s) decide the status, and handle this status in the frontend.

Ok thanks for clarifying. My resource server returns 401 for authorized requests (those without a valid JWT token). As you suggested, I've included in my BFF, an authentication end point handler, that returns 403 Forbidden - for when unauthenticated requests are made to the BFF. I have a few more bugs. I'm just working through them.

Read my answer and comments more carefully, I never suggested to return a 403 (that's Forbidden, not Unauthorized), and I wrote several times that it is not the responsibility of the BFF to decide the status of a response.

ok thanks. I must have misunderstood what you wrote here, in the context of my post on BFF - : You need 3 things: a (Server)AuthenticationEntryPoint setting the response status with something in the 3xx range - I'm guessing you meant this for the Resource Server then, not the BFF, to clarify?

Again, the first section gives the answer to your question (how to have the BFF redirect to login), and the second section (what is after the second title) explains why you should not do that. So you can configure the BFF with an authentication entry point returning a 302, but you should not. Is that clear enough?

Ok - I read it again. What you meant in simple words, was you can redirect, with a BFF (with the authentication entry point returning 302), but you SHOULD NOT.  It is the business of the Front End (e.g. Angular) to do any redirections after receiving error codes originating from the Resource Server, using an interceptor of some sort. Seems to make sense. I'll remvove the authentication entry point from the BFF then. CORS is not an issue since I followed your articles guidance to use a reverse proxy. I just have a few bugs left.

My last bug! Not sure if you can help with it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78858881/spring-oauth-client-wont-redirect-when-spring-auth-server-receives-invalid-cr
